# Optimal way of creating primary key on huge heap table of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, partitioning, sql-server-2017

I have a table with 2 billion data sizing around 100 GB on SQL Server 2017.
Need to delete data older than d-30.

So creating partition for each date to leverage truncate table with partition number option.

So to place partition in place need to drop and recreate primary key in table.

Above said is an example, in real time there are multiple tables I need to do it for multiple such tables.

I have two questions here.

1. What is the optimal way of creating pk in table? what I need to consider while recreating pk
2. How to estimate duration of creating pk on a table? Required for planning when to run.

Note : Tables are already be in sorted order because it had pk previously but we dropped.

Existing table design :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].testtable
(
    [ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    col1 [varchar](1024) NULL,
    col2 [varchar](1024) NULL,
    col3 [varchar](1024) NULL,
    col4 [bigint] NULL,
    col5 [bigint] NULL,
    col6 [bigint] NOT NULL,
    col7 [varchar](20) NULL,
    col8 [varchar](250) NULL,
    [run_date] [date] not NULL ,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,  
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Partition : a partition for a day based on run date . partition will be available for 30 days in prod. Here only 6 days for sampling

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [run_date_partitionfunction](date) 
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES 
(N'2020-12-25', N'2020-12-26', N'2020-12-27', N'2020-12-28', N'2020-12-29', N'2020-12-30')

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [run_date_partitionschema] 
AS PARTITION [run_date_partitionfunction] 
TO ([PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY])
```

Table proposal in future

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].testtable
(
    [ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    col1 [varchar](1024) NULL,
    col2 [varchar](1024) NULL,
    col3 [varchar](1024) NULL,
    col4 [bigint] NULL,
    col5 [bigint] NULL,
    col6 [bigint] NOT NULL,
    col7 [varchar](20) NULL,
    col8 [varchar](250) NULL,
    [run_date] [date] not NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC, [run_date] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [run_date_partitionschema]([run_date])
) ON [run_date_partitionschema]([run_date])
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you need to delete the vast majority of a table, it's easier to copy the needed data into another table with the exact same DDL and indexes, truncate the original, then [`ALTER TABLE SWITCH`](https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2016/11/15/3521/swapping-data-sets) to swap the data in. You may need to disable foreign keys at the same time

Comment: Please provide the table definition.  And explain why you have the `PRIMARY KEY` that you chose.

Comment: @RickJames : added code as requested, and having pk on table will boost the performance in inserting, we have pk on id column which is unique for table

Comment: It looks like ID+Date is unique, but ID, by itself, might not be.  Are you saying that INSERT always includes `ID`?

Comment: id itself unique, saying based on data i have. but not enforced in table structure. And YES we always pass id in all inserts